# Running shell script with sarge eats my quotes

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess, sh

I'm trying to execute shell-script with [sarge](http://sarge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library.
My file `script.sh` has this content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
export LOCAL_PROJECT_ROOT=/path/to/the/dir
inotifywait -mr --exclude '(.git|.idea|node_modules)' \
-e modify,create,delete ${LOCAL_PROJECT_ROOT} --format '%w%f'
```

And I run it like with sarge:

```
sarge.run('sh script.sh')
```

I see with `htop` that no `inotifywait` process is running.
However, when I run this script directly in the shell with `sh script.sh`, everything works as expected.

If I remove `--exclude` and `--format` parts which both contain quoted arguments, sarge runs fine too.

It runs fine with sarge too if I rewrite the script into something like this:

```
echo "inotifywait -mr --exclude '(.git|.idea|node_modules)' -e modify,create,delete ${LOCAL_PROJECT_ROOT} --format '%w%f'" | /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like Module issue.

Because :

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:49:48) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 'a' == "a"
True
>>> '%s' %"'a'"
"'a'"
>>> "%s" %'"a"'
'"a"'
>>>
```

Maybe :

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
export LOCAL_PROJECT_ROOT=/path/to/the/dir
inotifywait -mr --exclude "(.git|.idea|node_modules)" -e modify,create,delete ${LOCAL_PROJECT_ROOT} --format "%w%f"
```

1. Escaping character is undefined '\' [check this](https://github.com/vsajip/sarge/blob/master/sarge/shlext.py)
2. Next line character is `\n`, but you got "\\n"
3. You only run `inotifywait -mr --exclude '(.git|.idea|node_modules)'`
   That's not enough for Shell.

Comment: While your direct `maybe` didn't help me, and your 1/2/3 haven't helped either (because I have other parts of the script with escaping character and next line character and they work), your answer helped me to experiment with this a bit further and get an acceptable result:
```inotifywait -mr --exclude "(.git|.idea|node_modules)" -e modify,create,delete ${LOCAL_PROJECT_ROOT} --format "'%w%f'"
```
As you see, changing single quotes to double quotes work in the first case, but not in the second one, where I should wrap single quotes in double quotes instead. Weird, but works, thank you :)